# Prove that grammar accepting arithmetic expressions is not regular

Tags: automata, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

I created a grammar which accepts all arithmetic expressions consisting of $+,-,*,/, (, )$.

I created the following grammar:

> $S \rightarrow M+-M$
>
> $+-M \rightarrow +M+-M$
>
> $+-M \rightarrow -M+-M$
>
> $+-M \rightarrow \epsilon $
>
> $M \rightarrow E*/E$
>
> $*/E \rightarrow *E*/E$
>
> $*/E \rightarrow /E*/E$
>
> $*/E \rightarrow \epsilon$
>
> $E \rightarrow a$
>
> $E \rightarrow (S)$

Where S is sum and our starting symbol, +,-,*,/,(,),a are terminal symbols and S,M, +-M, E, */E, () are nonterminals.

Now the question is, how do I prove that such grammar can't be regular?

Comment: Maybe try to write something with brackets `(, )` and try to use the pumping lemma.

Comment: What do you mean try to write something with brackets?

Comment: Any expression that you want, as long as you put as many brackets as possible.

Comment: The idea is to use the fact that brackets come in pairs to ensure problems when you try to use the pumping lemma

Comment: Your grammar isn't even context free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets call this language $L$ and assume towards contradiction that it is regular.

We build the following homomorphism $h:\Sigma\rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ by:

$$h(x)=\cases{0&$x=`(`$\\1 &$x=`)`$\\\epsilon&otherwise}$$

Since regular languages are closed under homomorphism, then $h(L)$ is regular as  well. Now, lets take a look at the following language: $\hat L:=h(L)\cap L(0^*1^*)$.

Clearly, $\hat L$ is regular as the intersection of two regular languages. But also, its not hard to see that $\hat L=\{0^n1^n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and we know this language isn't regular.

Hence we got a contradiction, meaning that $L$ couldn't have been regular.

Comment: Why is  $\hat L$ not regular?

Comment: its a well known language that isnt regular. If you want a simple proof, use the pumping lemma